# What is the current status of Java scripting? (i.e., JSR 223 or successors)

Tags: java, jsr223

I would like to add scripting capability to events in an existing Java application.  Looking about, I find JSR 223 for Java scripting.  But it is withdrawn, and [wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_for_the_Java_Platform) that

> it was decided that this functionality would be included as an integral part of Java 9 and onward.

Yet looking at [the wikipedia page on Java SE versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) I see nothing from Java SE 9 onward to the present time (Java SE 16, under development) that sounds like "scripting" to me.

So what is the current recommended approach to integrate a scripting facility into an existing Java program? (And did I miss something in Java SE 9+ that speaks to this?)  (Or does the fact that it *does* show up in Java SE 8 on that wikipedia page mean that it actually got in "early" - for some definition of "early" that includes being in a late release ...)

Comment: It's complicated. Use [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/). Or decide which language you want to use with which version of Java and look for an implementation. Nashorn or Rhino if you want to embed JavaScript. Jython for Python. Etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - does using `GraalVM` mean its part of a particular implementation, not officially "Java" per se?  And both Rhino (earlier) and Nashorn (later) have been deprecated and removed from Java, if I'm understanding that version page correctly.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I guess at this time I'm more-or-less scripting language agnostic - what I'm wondering about is if I'm looking for scripting language engines that support JSR 223 or something else?

Comment: At this time, it's largely irrelevant. And GraalVM seems to be the direction Oracle is pursuing. So if you want to know the "official" line, it seems to be that. Seldom does a use case involve supporting multiple scripting languages; which makes JSR 223 a "nice to have" (not a necessity). And, in some cases, you have to fiddle with the scripting language implementation internals anyway (which makes JSR 223 impractical). I've done a large project with Nashorn. It was *interesting*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - ok, thanks!

Comment: there are many languages that supports JSR223 kotlin,velocity,groovy,... and Java supports it, is your question what are the changes from Java 9?

Comment: @user7294900 - My question is: JSR-223 is officially withdrawn.  Are you suggesting it is still supported?  So does "withdrawn" merely mean (in this case) that it is now officially supported so it doesn't need to be a "JSR" anymore?  (Because I didn't know that, if true.  Doesn't seem to be stated anywhere?  I don't know the JSR process at all but wouldn't there be another status for that, like "accepted"?)

Comment: @user7294900 - And another possibility is that the Wikipedia page simply missed it as a Java 9 feature and I'm looking in the wrong place for a list of "new features of Java by version" because ... Wikipedia ...

Comment: There were enhancements since java 7 until java 8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/enhancements.html#jdk1.4

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ignore the withdrawn status, especially because it's already working/embedded to Java

I'm looking at your [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) and it states that JSR 223 in on Java SE 8

> JSR 223, JEP 174: Project Nashorn, a JavaScript runtime which allows developers to embed JavaScript code within applications

and even Java 6:

> Scripting Language Support (JSR 223): Generic API for tight integration with scripting languages, and built-in Mozilla JavaScript Rhino integration.

Actually there were enhancements since [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/enhancements.html#jdk1.4)

> **Enhancements in Java SE 7**
> The JDK 7 release is co-bundled with the Mozilla Rhino JavaScript engine based on version 1.7R3 pre-release sources with Oracle modifications. You can download the Oracle modified Rhino sources at java.net.